# PHP drupal added css file does not appear in page source

Tags: 7, theming

I have enabled LessCSS on my site and I have a node instance where I want to add a specific CSS.

I used the following piece of code:

```
<?php
    drupal_add_css( '/sites/MyStuff/introduction.css');
?>
<div id="myid" class="box">
    ....some text
</div>
```

Yet, there is no import or link statement in my page source code for `introduction.css`. I am not using compression. FireBug does not mention loading an `introduction.css` file. I have doubled-checked and the file is properly located in the folder.

What could cause this issue? And how to solve it?

**P.S.:**

The css file contains the following:

```
.box {
    color: green;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The styling is not applied on the page.

Comment: Try `drupal_add_css( 'sites/MyStuff/introduction.css');`, without the leading `'/'`

Comment: I tried but it did not work. Apparently, it is too late in the process to call this method (i.e., from the node body), says: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410494/drupal-add-css-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410494/drupal-add-css-not-working, the solution is to use [CSS Injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector). I tried and it worked.

**Update**

I maintain a [page](http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-add-css-script-in-head-section.html) explaining how to use CSS Injector too add CSS to a page.